# Clearing list items without being able to edit the HTML?

Tags: css, html-lists, clearfix

I am using a Wordpress plugin which generates an unordered list, I can modify the layout with CSS but I cannot edit the HTML(to insert a clearfix div after the last `li`). I am trying to create a grid from the list using `float:left;` and trying to figure out how I can apply a clearfix to the list items so that the `ul` does not have a height of 0. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-right:3%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  width:30%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1xf7msh/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make the ul encompass all floated children, and clear the fix as well:

```
ul {
overflow: auto;
}
```